# How to find a date and number from a file, with Get Current Date?

Tags: automated-tests, robotframework, return-value

I have a file, dates.txt, which has dates in dd.mm.yyyy format, and a number next to it, and now I need to return just the number on correct date. I use Get Current Date and for example, on 15.08.2023, I need to the robot to grab the 44253 next to it. Any tips?

I tried to find answers, but couldn't find any thats suitable for my needs.

EDIT: fixed example, 8-> 08, added information, and cleaned up the question a little.

The data in the dates.txt are like this

```
08.05.2024     608243
09.05.2024     323409
10.05.2024     934510
11.05.2024     637343
```

So the date, and a couple of spaces before the number. The file itself is not too important, so changes can be made, as long as I can get the number on the correct date.

Only looking for solutions in Robot Framework.

Comment: Your example contradicts with your requirements. In my understanding (and I think for most people who program) `mm` means 2 characters indicating month so correct for August would be 08. Is anything else except digit in line?

Comment: Fixed the month. Everything should be right now. Also added some information about how the data is in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
*** Settings ***
Library    DateTime
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    String

*** Test Cases ***
DemoCase
    ${number}    Get Todays Number

*** Keywords ***
Get Todays Number
    ${dates}    Get File    dates.txt
    ${now}    Get Current Date    result_format=%d.%m.%Y
    ${lines}    Split To Lines    ${dates}
    FOR    ${line}    IN    @{lines}
        ${date}    ${right}    Split String    ${line}    ${SPACE}    max_split=1
        IF    "${date}" == "${now}"
            ${number}    Set Variable    ${right.strip()}
            RETURN    ${number}
        END
    END
    Fail    Was not able to find number for "${now}"
```

Comment: This must be really close, thank you for the answer. It tells me that Cannot set variables: Expected 2 return values, got 1. Must be a problem with how the data is in the .txt?

Comment: I got to work. I dont know, if it should be done like this, but it works. Can you edit this into the answer, or fix the answer, so I can mark it as the right one? I removed ${SPACE} and max_split=1. I also swapped RETURN to Log To Console, and added Set Test Variable ${number}. I also removed the Fail. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Baldie, well return statement in a keyword and failing nothing found is definitely not a bad thing. Split string very much depends on actual data in a line. For case where it's dd.mm.yyyy multiple spaces (\x20) and number it works, for other types of spaces it will not work.